# How to correctly run tensorflow lite inference on Android with CSV as input?

Tags: android, csv, tensorflow, kotlin, tensorflow-lite

I have a tflite model expecting an input shape of (1, 1000, 12). Just to test it, I'm intending to load a CSV file and run inference on it. Below is my code and the relevant portion of the error msg that I get when running it.

I assume I'm making a mistake in properly loading or reading the CSV file. I'm relatively new to Android and would gladly appreciate any help on this matter!

```
val testModel = myModel.newInstance(context)

// Creates inputs for reference.
val inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, 1000, 12), DataType.FLOAT32)

val openRawResource = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.inputdata).readBytes()
val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(openRawResource)

// inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer)
inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer)

// Runs model inference and gets result.
val outputs = testModel.process(inputFeature0)
val outputFeature0 = outputs.outputFeature0AsTensorBuffer

// Releases model resources if no longer used.
model.close()
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The size of byte buffer and the shape do not match.
        at org.tensorflow.lite.support.common.SupportPreconditions.checkArgument(SupportPreconditions.java:104)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.support.tensorbuffer.TensorBuffer.loadBuffer(TensorBuffer.java:296)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.support.tensorbuffer.TensorBuffer.loadBuffer(TensorBuffer.java:323)
        at com.example.ecgclassifier.MainActivity.analyze(MainActivity.kt:47)
        at com.example.ecgclassifier.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:23)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pleas make sure the above raw resource byte array has a float buffer array for the tensor, shaped [1, 1000, 12].

The error message said that the given byte array from the `byteBuffer` is not matched with the size requirement for the float tensor with the [1, 1000, 12] shape.